# Metered Billing with In App Subscriptions on App Stores

Tags: firebase, google-play, stripe-payments, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

I have a service using Firebase with Stripe and metered billing. I charge customers for each document they have stored in their main Collection.  However, in the signup process, they have to sign up on my web site and their users and admins download the app for free from the app stores to interact.

I'm thinking hard about punting the web site sign up and just going through the app stores and paying their fee.  However, I can't seem to unlock how to charge a per seat metering based on my firebase collection list.  The number of seats can vary from 1 - 1,000.

The way Stripe does this is quite easy, one bill to the customer, and I update the usage every night and it bills based on the highest reported number in the period.  I see greater potential in creating signup in the app.  However, I can't do that with Stripe, circumventing the app stores with my model...or at least I don't think I can, and I can't figure out a per seat metered subscription setup in the app stores.

Core question:

1. How could I get firebase metered stripe billing to pass through the app stores?
2. How can I set up in app subscriptions based on per seat metered billing from firebase data?

Maybe I can get away with this if I can demonstrate to the app stores that they lack the functionality?